# What are the rated voltage and current of a single wire within an ethernet cable?

Tags: ethernet, poe

I haven't been able to find a clear cut answer to this question. I've found online somewhere that the entire cable can carry a max of 57V. Each pair can carry a max of 960mA. Is there any validity to this information? Does this mean that a single wire within the ethernet cable can carry about 7.125V and about 480mA?

Comment: Are you asking what the nominal voltage of the signal is? Or perhaps its min/max for data validity?  Or the insulation rating of the cable?

Comment: Which Ethernet standard? Which cable category or class? Cable type and manufacturer? Power over Ethernet or not? For what purpose will the cable be used, Ethernet or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [PoE Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_over_Ethernet) cables certified for use with **802.3bt Type 4, 4PPoE or PoE++** are rated for 960mA per pair at 57V-DC max.

**(1)** In general, the current capcity of a cable is a function of `max. allowed temprature rise, length, cross-section, material used and type of termination`.

In my opinion, a common Ethernet-Jack (not designed for PoE) is the bottlebeck - not the cable itself - when it comes to max. DC current.

**(2)** In general, the voltage rating of a cable is a function of `insulation used, insulation tickness, distance between cables, type of cross-section/how the cable is wound.`

Ethernet beeing a twisted-pair cable designed for data-transmission is therefore not made for high-voltage DC-transmission in general.

**(3)** To answer your questions: If a cable is rated for 57V-DC, each single conductor can sustain at least 57V-DC relative to any other conductor within this cable. So you can e.g. safely connect 57V to a single conductor and all other seven to GND.

If `a pair` is rated for 960mA DC, the rating of a single conductor depends on how this pair is used to transmitt the current.

If a pair is connected to V+ and another pair is used as GND return-path, then every single conductor is rated for 480mA DC.

If a conductor of this pair is used as V+ and the other conductor is used as GND, then every conductor is rated for 960mA.

**(4)** If you intend to use a Ethernet cable in a custom application, where power transmission along data-transmission is required, you can refere to [Cat 5 Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_5_cable) standards. There, a max. DC Voltage of 125V and a DC-Loop resistance of smaller 0.188Ohm/Meter is specified. Cat 5 is a `bulk standard villy nilly available everywhere for cheap cable type`. I myself have used this to transmitt 24VDC/100mA alongside RS485 16MBit/s in several applications without any problems. I have also seen this kind of usage in industrial, medical, automotive (Test-equipment), multimedia, home applicance and general applications. In my experience, the Ethernet-Jacks are the "DC and realiability" problems of these solutions.

Answer (score 1):

There is no clear answer.

It depends what cable you buy so their material and insulation determines how much voltage the cable withstands and the conductive wire diameter and material together with allowed temperature rise will determine how much current it supports.

Answer (score 1):

Currents are additive over the number of conductors (more or less).  Voltage rating is the same regardless of how many conductors you are using.  (E.g. two 100V 1A rated wires in parallel can carry 2A at 100V, *not* 2A at 200V).  The specific ratings depend on the cable you are using.  Ethernet cable can be found from 22 to 30 AWG and there are probably some specialty cables outside that range.  The formulas for bare wire ampacity are likely to be inadequate since ethernet cable is twisted, bundled, sometimes shielded, and then finally jacketed.  Just poking around, I can't find ampacity ratings on the datasheets I can find, so I'd say 22 to 24 AWG cable is probably your best choice if you want to push almost half an amp through it.  Those super-thin cables you can find on Amazon or wherever are not going to be adequate.

Comment: A specific Belden 72002PU cable is rated 1.4A per conductor and 450 VDC / 300 VAC. Any generic cable may be rated for minimal limits for certain category or class cable. It also depends which specific Ethernet standard we are talking about here.